# Retrieving all similar key values of Cypress fixture JSON data

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I am having quite a bit of difficulty finding a clean way to retrieve the value of all values from the same key in objects in a Cypress fixture JSON file.

For example, in the below JSON file (called `myPeople.json`) I only want the `firstName` values for *all* objects under `people`.

```
{
    "people":[
        {
            "firstName":"Bob",
            "lastName":"Dawson"
        },
        {
            "firstName":"Tom",
            "lastName": "Wild"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Sally",
            "lastName": "Rose"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I want to retrieve all the objects under `people`, I can execute `cy.fixture("myPeople").its("people)` and it will return all the objects beautifully.

Getting *all* of the firstName values back has proven to be difficult. I have attempted the following methods of retrieving these values, but they don't do what I would anticipate them to do.

```
cy.fixture("myPeople").its("people").its("firstName") //This doesn't work likely because it expects a specific object under the people node to look up its firstName key's value
```

However, if I pass in an explicit index, it will return that index's firstName value:

```
cy.fixture("myPeople").its("people").its(0).its("firstName") //This returns the value "Bob".
```

What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without regard to Cypress per se, it seems you want to use the JavaScript `map` function.

For instance:

```
let people = {
  "people": [
    {
      "firstName": "Bob",
      "lastName": "Dawson"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Tom",
      "lastName": "Wild"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Sally",
      "lastName": "Rose"
    }
  ]
}

let firstNames = people.people.map(person => person.firstName)

console.log(firstNames) // --> [ 'Bob', 'Tom', 'Sally' ]
```

More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: In Cypress, you can apply `map()` like this `cy.fixture("myPeople").its("people").then(people => people.map(p => p.firstName))`

Comment: I knew it was something minor I was completely overthinking. This did the trick, thank you. @Ackroydd also provided a succinct solution for Cypress specifically that worked well.

Answer (score 0):

One option can be to use a simple for loop and access all your array elements from your fixtures file.

```
describe('Get first Name from fixtures', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    //Load Fixture File
    cy.fixture('myPeople.json').as('myPeople')
  })

  it('Test', () => {
    cy.get('@myPeople').then((myPeople) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < myPeople.people.length; i++) {
        //Print the first Names
        cy.log(myPeople.people[i].firstName)
      }
    })
  })
})
```